# Python implementation of Conway's Game of life with Pygame

Tags: python, performance, game-of-life, pygame

So I've started learning programming a few months ago and this is one of my first projects. The program works, but I feel like it's a bit slow compared to the other implementations of Conway's Game of life. Is there any ways I could speed up my code ?

```
import numpy
import copy
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random

pygame.init()

height = 400
width = 400
block_size = 4
window = pygame.display.set_mode((height,width),DOUBLEBUF)
window.set_alpha(None)
alive = (255,255,255)
dead = (0,0,0)


def check(y_axis,x_axis,grid):
    tmp_grid = copy.copy(grid)
    for y in range(1,y_axis-1):
        for x in range(1,x_axis-1):
            a = 0
            for i in range(-1,2):
                for j in range(-1,2):
                    if grid[y+i][x+j] == 1:
                        a += 1
            if grid[y][x] == 1:
                a -= 1
                if a < 2 or a > 3:
                    tmp_grid[y][x] = 0
            elif grid[y][x] == 0:
                if a == 3:
                    tmp_grid[y][x] = 1
    grid = tmp_grid
    return grid

def display(y_axis,x_axis,grid):
    rects = []
    for y in range(1,y_axis-1):
        for x in range(1,x_axis-1):
            rect = pygame.Rect(x*block_size, y*block_size, block_size, block_size)
            if grid[x][y] == 1:
                rects.append(pygame.draw.rect(window,alive,rect))
            elif grid[x][y] == 0:
                rects.append(pygame.draw.rect(window,dead,rect))
    pygame.display.update(rects)

def generate(y_axis,x_axis,grid):
    for y in range(1,y_axis-1):
        for x in range(1,x_axis-1):
            alive_or_dead = random.randint(0,1)
            if alive_or_dead:
                grid[y][x] = 1
            else:
                grid[y][x] = 0

def main():
    y_axis = height//block_size
    x_axis = width//block_size
    grid = numpy.zeros((y_axis,x_axis))
    generate(y_axis,x_axis,grid)
    while True:
        display(y_axis,x_axis,grid)
        grid = check(y_axis,x_axis,grid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In your `generate` function, `numpy.random.randint` can do everything you need. I'd suggest renaming the function to `generate_grid` and just returning the generated grid.
2. In your `display` and `check` functions, the `grid` parameter knows its own size - you don't need to pass that in.
3. In `display`, your `alive` and `dead` colors could be in a tuple. Then you could index the tuple by [0] or [1] (the value of the cell) to determine the color:

   ```
   rect = pygame.Rect(x*block_size, y*block_size, block_size, block_size)

   rects.append(pygame.draw.rect(window, Colors[grid[x][y]], rect)
   ```
4. Pretty much everything with a dot (.) or an expression should be cached inside `display`.

   ```
   pgrect = pygame.Rect
   rappend = rects.append
   drawrect = pygame.draw.rect
   ```
5. Your x/y loop can be replaced using `np.apply_over_axes`
6. The `scipy.signal.convolve2d` function will do most of the heavy lifting for you in terms of neighbor counting &c

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't understand how I can implement the functions np.apply_over_axes and scipy.signal.convolve2d, I've looked at the documentation, but I don't really understand what they do.

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late but I hope it will help someone else!
You would use scipy.signal.convolve like this

```
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), dtype=np.int8)
kernel[1, 1] = 0
neighborarray =  signal.convolve(grid, kernel, mode='same'))
```

this gives you an array of all the neigboring alive cells, `[i][j]` remains the same,
now just compare `neighborarray[i][j]` to the rules of game of life and thats it!
Example:

```
[[0 1 1],
 [0 0 0],
 [1 0 0]]
```

would give you

```
[[1 1 1],
 [2 3 2],
 [0 1 0]]
```